# Detect a url in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an iPhone app where I take the twitter feeds to a table view.currently I'm inserting a label as a sub view to the table cell to display multiple details.What I want to do is to detect urls inside that label where when we touch the urls,it should open up in safari.How can I do that?.....Hope you guys will help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not straightforward to do with just what's provided in the iPhone SDK.

Fortunately, the [Three20 library](http://github.com/facebook/three20) has a `TTStyledTextLabel` that supports exactly what you want.

Here is a screenshot (using `TTStyledTextTableItemCell` which is a table cell with a `TTStyledTextLabel`):

[image]

Comment: Well,I'm currently using MGTwitterEngine.Is there a way to do this other than using Three20?....

Thanks.